# Where did the Red Brick Road lead to?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz

In the movie of "The Wizard of Oz", the beginning of the Yellow Brick Road is entwined with the beginning of a Red Brick Road. The Yellow Brick Road led to the Emerald City. Where did the Red Brick Road go?

[image: Movie still showing the red and yellow brick roads in a spiral pattern entwined together, Dorothy and Toto set off down the yellow brick road with a crowd encircling them]

Comment: Rome.  All roads lead to Rome.

Comment: There's no place like Rome.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Interestingly, I have two (possibly conflicting) answers.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_brick_road#Story):

> In the 1939 film, a red brick road can be seen starting at the same
> point as the Yellow Brick Road but going in a different direction.
> This road does not exist in the books.

<strike>From [Askville.Amazon.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20120503003050/http://askville.amazon.com/Red-Brick-Road/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=35953224):</strike>

> **No one knows for sure....**
>
> In the original series of Oz books written by L. Frank Baum the red
> brick road goes to the Quadling Country in Oz. Red is the Quadlings'
> state color.
>
> In his books, the Land of Oz was divided into four
> quadrants and each was designated a particular color: Winkie Country =
> Yellow, Gillikin Country = Purple, Munchkin Country = Blue, and
> Quadling Country = Red. Glinda the Good was the ruler of the Quadlings
> in L. Frank Baum's Oz series. As her bubble floats away from
> Munchkinland in the 1939 film, it appears to be following the red
> brick road. Therefore, the red brick road most likely leads back to
> her homeland, Quadling Country.
>
> [image: Map entitled "The Marvelous Land of Oz" showing Emerald City in green in the centre with the northern pueple area Gillikin Country, Eastern blue area Munchkin Country, southern red area Quadling Country and the yellow western area Winkie Country]

I'm inclined to go with the answer from Askville, since it may simply mean that the road wasn't in the Munchkin town in the books.  (I haven't read any of them)

Thanks to Pixel's link, I also did some searching through the books.  Not only is he and Wikipedia right in that a "red brick" road is never mentioned, there is a passage that specifically suggests that the road is not red - from [The Patchwork Girl of Oz](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/32094/pg32094.txt), 84% down the webpage (near the beginning of chapter 25, bolding mine):

> Not that the trees and grasses were red, but the fences and houses
> were painted that color and all the **wild-flowers that bloomed by the
> wayside had red blossoms**. This part of the Quadling Country seemed
> peaceful and prosperous, if rather lonely, and the **road was now more
> distinct and easier to follow**.

The map above does appear to be correct, however.  The Quadling country is, in general, associated with the color red, and is located in the South.  So I feel it's pretty likely that the movie made some slight alterations, such that the yellow brick roads all eventually led to the Winkie country (and from Munchkin country, meant you'd go right through the Emerald City), and the red brick road to the Quadling country.  If the movie encompassed more, a purple brick road and a blue brick road may have been added as well.

Comment: I just did a full-text search for the string "red brick" in the digital version of The Wonderful Wizard of Oz on Project Gutenberg, and there are no hits. I did quick search through all the other books with Oz in the title and didn't find any hits there either, so this road doesn't seem to be discussed in the books. (See http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?query=oz)

Comment: @Pixel Interesting, but I'm getting a 403 Forbidden from that link, apparently due to overzealous bot protections.  If you look closely at the image, it says in the bottom right, "The International Wizard of Oz Club".  Could there be extra canon material, or would that not have been made by Baum?

Comment: There is one confused aspect in the movie. In the books, there are two good witches: Glinda in the south and another in the north. They were combined in the movie into a single character Glinda, the Good Witch of the North. Also, Iskata, there is additional canon material not written by Baum. The Wikipedia article does an ok job of sorting out which of the many books are/are not canon.

Comment: @Izkata, sorry, I edited your post because I didn't realize that there was a comment box. Actually, if you look closely at the picture of Dorthy starting out on the yellow brick road, there appear to be two blue brick roads, coming from where the red brick road is headed, and where the yellow brick road is headed, and ending right where the yellow and red brick roads start, which makes sense seeing as blue is the color of munchkin land, and that is where Dorthy is at that point, although this still doesn't explain why there is no purple brick road, it gives the second theory a bit more support

Comment: The Yellow brick road does not just lead to the Emerald City (or beyond it to Winkie County) - it leads in a circuitous path all around Oz, and only eventually into the Emerald City.  It would be great if there were roads from each county's capital to each other like that, but if that were the case, there should also be GREEN brick roads leading to the emerald city from each place.  

The books just don't support this theory though.

Comment: @Ryno The books may not, but my theory at the bottom is that, along with a few other known changes, this was a tweak or assumption they made that makes the movie differ from the books

Answer (score 18):

As you can see from this photo, the red "road" leads directly alongside the bushes by the bridge over the Munchkin river and then simply **stops dead**. There appears to be a cutting where a road *could go*, but the road itself ends in a bush.

[image: The red brick road splits from the yellow away from the town centre and runs alongside a river until it just ends]

Comment: "British humour"

Comment: I can't help it, I'm British.

Comment: That's just a bad angle; [you can see in this video starting at 1:30 that it keeps going](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=80&v=x6D8PAGelN8)

Comment: @Izkata - You're right. The road appears to end a few yards further along. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

I went back and re-watched the movie scene, and read that passage in the novel, before making this an answer but I'm now pretty convinced that there *is no* red brick road. It seems like there's a road because of the way the yellow brick road is laid out on the set.

As mentioned in other answers, there's no red brick road in the original novel. In the movie, we can see a sort of double-spiral of red and yellow bricks starting from a central location and moving out.

However, I don't think the red bricks actually represent a road. Rather, the pavilion that marks the terminus of the yellow brick road is a paved circle of red bricks. The spiral shape of the yellow brick road basically leaves a counterpart spiral of red bricks in the spaces where the yellow brick road happens to not be. This *looks* like a second spiral road because it has a nearly identical shape.

If you watch the scene at the part where Dorothy hits the "main part" of the road, the red bricks veer off screen-right (to Dorothy's left) in an arc that appears to simply be the edge of the circular pavilion. In particular, it *looks* to me like the red part is getting thinner as the last loop of yellow nears the edge of the pavilion. It's hard to tell because there's some kind of stone structure in the way, but there isn't any on-screen indication that the red bricks "go" anywhere.

[image: Dorothy and Toto follow the yellow brick road away from the town centre with the crowds following them; the yellow/red spiral of the centre can be seen in the background where the red appears to just end]

Comment: That's just a bad angle; [you can see in this video starting at 1:30 that it keeps going](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=80&v=x6D8PAGelN8)

Answer (score 2):

It has been years since I read *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz* (from my grandmother's book case).  I vaguely seem to remember that the book suggested that from Munchkin Land there were THREE roads from where Dorothy left on her adventure:  the Yellow, the Red, and the Purple.

I have also read somewhere the roads were colored so that the Munchkins knew their directions, inferring they were not totally compass wise.  Another reference seems to suggest that the Four Roads of Oz also met up at the center of The Emerald city as well - which infers  that there had to have been four main doors to the city.

Comment: Sorry, the original book only mentions "the" Yellow Brick Road, no other colors. It's later books that mention there's a 2nd yellow brick road in Munchkinland (they split near the poppy fields outside the Emerald City, near Restwater Lake). The movie adds the Red Brick Road, as well as the intersection where Dorthy meets the Scarecrow.

Answer (score -2):

The Core Rulebook for the RPG "Oz Dark and Terrible" is a compilation of all of the facts from Baum's books with the exception of Dorothy's arrival into Oz(due to the fact that her arrival was such a huge catalyst for change). In the back of the book it has a map of all of Oz and it make no mention of a red brick road, but instead shows not one but five yellow brick roads throughout Oz.

Comment: I don't believe this is an answer; moswt likely solution is to make it a comment.

Comment: For what it's worth, [The Wonderful Wiki of Oz](http://oz.wikia.com/wiki/Oz:_Dark_and_Terrible) implies that many, if not most of the facts from that game to be less than completely accurate to Baum's version.